# YAML Error: Inconsistent indentation level

Tags: perl, yaml

I'm using the Perl YAML module, and I kept getting the error message:

```
YAML Error: Inconsistent indentation level
   Code: YAML_PARSE_ERR_INCONSISTENT_INDENTATION
   Line: 2
   Document: 1
 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/YAML.pm line 36
```

In my Perl code, I did `my $config = YAML::LoadFile("files.yaml");`

and here is the content of the files.yaml file:

```
--- #input files to be processed  
files: all my files  
    - file1  
    - file2  
    - file3  
    - file4  
    - file5
```

It seems to me that it's correctly formatted. Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You’re mixing syntax up. Take out the `all my files` and you should see it parse fine, creating a hash with files -> array ref of files.